# save sorted order in database

Tags: sorting

I'm a webdeveloper and at the moment I'm using a very annoying and i think to difficult method for my cms for the following;

I'm making a gallery and I want to give the user the choice how to order/sort the images. so he can change the order of showing them (http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/). 
but what to do next; how to safe this order in the database? at the moment I have a extra table with the id's, in which order they have to appear on the website. way to difficult thinking I guess.

who knows a better method? this is hard to maintain aswel. I'm working with codeigniter, and jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Add one extra field [photo_ord]  to your Database table for Image_Order
Create Image List

```
<li class="left" id="someId">        
<a href="#" >
<img src="image path here" alt="error" id="image_id_here" class="img_thumb"/>
</a>
</li>
```

Function handler (It Will called when any image will move)

```
<a href="#" onclick="change_order()" class="btn_1">Save Order</a>
```

Function will make ajax call for Update Image-Order

```
function change_order()
{
    var urlst="";
    var co=1;
    $('.img_thumb').each(function()
    {
        urlst=urlst+this.id+'#'+co+'*';
        co++;
    });
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"xhr_change_image_order.php",
        data:"orader="+urlst,
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data=="changed")
                alert("Image order changed.");            
        },
        error:function()
        {
            alert('error occure');
        }
    });
}
```

File : xhr_change_image_order.php (will Update Database)

```
<?php    
$url = $_POST['orader'];
$photo_arr = explode("*", $url);
foreach ($photo_arr as $k => $ph) {
    if (strlen($ph) > 1) 
    {
          // Update Query 
          // $arr[0]  will contain image id
          // $arr[1]  will contain image order            
            UPDATE `photo` SET `photo_ord` =  $arr[1]  WHERE `photo_id` = $arr[0];
    }
}
echo "changed";
?>
```

After that when create Gallery Simply fetch data using ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT * FROM photo ORDER BY  photo_ord asc or DESC
```